# Blueprint CSS Extjs and JQuery in the same page, best way to make them coexist without conflict

Tags: jquery, extjs, blueprint-css

I have a web page that needs references to jQuery and Blueprint and extjs, I ve seen some docs for dealing with

(1) jquery and other libraries and
(2) extjs and other libraries

The docs I ve found also seem to contradict each other a bit, and reference older versions of the libs, so was wondering if anyone did this and what is the least painful path ( so this task doesnt take me a looong time)

Note: this site needs to support ie6 ( this is js stuff so I m sure this is a relevant piece of info)

Thanks for your help

Comment: have you tried searching here??.. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+no+conflict cause I think I already read something like it here that has been answered already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExtJS doesn't make use of the "$" selector, so there is no conflict between it and jQuery.  You can actually use jQuery as the base DOM manipulator for ExtJS, cutting down on the size of the JavaScript you're including.

Blueprint CSS won't cause any issues with the JavaScript, but might change the design of some of the ExtJS stuff.  The easiest way to get around this is to include the Blueprint CSS stuff **before** you include the ExtJS CSS; this way, ExtJS will override anything it needs, and you will have no issues.

Comment: Ive tried using the three togheter before I posted the question and there ARE problems with all of them, Blueprint gets in the way of extjs and viceversa no mather what order you put them in ( tho putting Blueprint looks better )

Comment: Those issues are likely not problems with ExtJS CSS and Blueprint CSS, but that ExtJS applies a class to all panel internals.  There's a configuration option you need to specify to tell it not to use it's own CSS for the inside of a container.  I'm unsure what it is, but the documentation should tell you.

Comment: It does seem like ExtJS is using the $ shorthand. I'm using Izenda AdHoc reporting tools in ASP.NET and my jQuery seems to blow up when I try to use the $.