# Apply red color for asterisk in a placeholder using ExtJS and CSS

Tags: css, extjs4.2, extjs5

I need to set * in red color in a textfield's placeholder to indicate that the field is mandatory to be filled. I'm using ExtJS with CSS.

[image]

Comment: Add your html for the input box.

Comment: I tried, but it doesnt work.

Comment: I can help. Let me know when you add your html here.

Comment: I added html tag like this --> emptyText: 'User Id<p>*</p>'

Answer (score 1):

Well not possible with `css` or `placeholder` attribute...You will need a hack by creating a element for the placeholder text like `span` and style it look like placeholder...

Also you will need some jQuery to check that the input is empty or not to just show or hide the placeholder text

```js
$(".input-control input").on("blur input", function() {
  if ($(this).val() != "") {
    $(this).next(".placeholder").hide();
  } else {
    $(this).next(".placeholder").show();
  }
})
```

```css
.input-control {
  position: relative;
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

.input-control input {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.input-control .placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #bbb;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.input-control .placeholder sup {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-control">
  <input type="text">
  <span class="placeholder">User Id<sup>*</sup></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using extjs, so can you format the code for that?

Comment: @DivakarArasu Actually I don't have any idea about extjs...I am just checking it...I will get back to you if I found anything...

Comment: @DivakarArasu you can read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776874/use-extjs-and-jquery-together-in-one-application

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to style different parts of placeholder text by default...

You can of course apply one style to the placeholder text though using the `::placeholder` attribute:

[Docs](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/)

However, there is a way to get support for *most* browsers that does what you require. There isn't a universal way of doing what you want easily so this might be a long shot...as long as you don't need support for older IE browsers, you should be okay with the following approach:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder:after {
    content: " *";
    color: red;
}

input:-moz-placeholder:after {
    content: " *";
    color: red;  
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder:after {  
    content: " *";
    color: red;  
}
```